# UPDATE QUERY Error - Error path name is not legal

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am a beginner to Windows forms and SQL Server so please forgive me for lousy codes.
I am trying to update the data on my SQL server based on the fields on my form.
This is the form,

[image]

This is the Choose Image button click event code,

```
String imgLocation = "";
private void btnInvChooseImg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFileDialog.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files (*.png)|.png|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog.Title = "Select Product Image";

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    imgLocation = openFileDialog.FileName.ToString();
                    pbInvImg.ImageLocation = imgLocation;
                }               

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

This is the Update button click event code,

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            if (txtProdName.Text != "" && txtProdDesc.Text != "" && txtQuantity.Text != "" && cmbAddCategory.Text != "" && pbInvImg.Image != null)
            {
                byte[] img = null;
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
                img = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE PRODUCTS 
                                            SET ProductImage = @img, 
                                                ProductName = '" + txtProdName.Text
                                                        + "', ProductDescription = '" + txtProdDesc.Text
                                                        + "', Quantity = '" + txtQuantity.Text
                                                        + "', CID = (SELECT CID FROM CATEGORY WHERE CategoryName = '" + cmbAddCategory.Text
                                                        + "') WHERE PID = '" + lblProdID.Text + "';", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Product updated successfully.");
                loadInventory();
                clearFields();

            }
            else if (txtProdName.Text == "" || txtProdDesc.Text == "" || txtQuantity.Text == "" || cmbAddCategory.Text == "" || pbInvImg.Image == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please supply all fields.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

The UPDATE works fine if I choose different image but if I only want to update/change the Product Name and not the image, an error occurs saying Error path name is not legal. Any idea what did I miss? Thank you.

Comment: I ***very*** strongly suggest you fix that injection issue in your application code. You *need* to use parametrised queries.

Comment: I always recommend testing queries in SQL Server Management Studio before running queries in c#.  The error messages are much better in SSMS than c#.

Comment: I guess that when you don't select a new file, the imgLocation is empty, so you cannot read the file (invalid path).  The other values like description are always filled in so updating is not giving you any errors when you have selected a new file.

Comment: @Wouter Yep, and I tried an if statement with parameter !string.IsNullOrEmpty() but still not working.

Comment: I suggest you implement an ORM such as EF (Entity Framework) When updating records, it is best to only update the fields that have actually changed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried debugging? It will help you know where the error is happening.

Most likely it is because imgLocation is null like @Wouter mentioned. You should check imgLocation before calling `FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`. This is where it is probably erroring.

```cs
if (File.Exists(imgLocation)) {
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
    img = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
}
else {
    # Tell them to choose a valid image or implement your own logic for what should happen.
    Message.Box($"The image at {imgLocation} doesn't exist. Please choose a valid image");
}
```

And parameterize your inputs. Please.

Comment: Hi thank you for the help sir, you're right the error is in the FileStream. I've tried your solution and it works. But I have to select different image first to update. But what Im trying to do is leave the image as is and just update the Product Name but when I click update it prompts me to "The image at {imgLocation} doesn't exist. Please choose a valid image". These fields were automatically populated if I click on a specific cell on my datagridview. That's why I want the user to have an option to wether select different image or not. Thank you so much for the help again sir.

Comment: You should then be able to assign `img` to be what the image previously was. I can't tell from the code how where you are storing your current image on load, but just assign that value to `img`.

Comment: Along with the other recommendations people have given in the comments on your question, you should also avoid storing the actual image in the database. Store the image in a file storage system and save a reference to the image in the database. You want to save `imgLocation`, not `img`.

Comment: I've fixed it already. Thank you all for the guidance and help. Much appreciated.